# How to kill Subprocess run by subprocess.Popen in Python (with code)

Tags: python, subprocess, kill

Firstly I would like to apologize in advance for my language skill, I am trying to bo my best to describe it clearly.

[Python run on Raspberri Pi3 B+]

I'm trying to kill subprocess run by subprocess.popen, I have tired searching all the web but all the solution couldn't works for me. I am beginner and not sure what i missed, I think It better to slove if someone can see my code

Here I have my code for run subprocess

```
pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"01-Subprogram-serial.py"])
```

01-Subprogram-serial.py << My subprogram

This is for video playing and LED control simultaneously by raspberri pi 3 b+

I am using Tkinter to run the button command for play video and run subprogram with serial device control, Subprogram works well only with first time running program but because of I cannot kill it, Subprogram still running even I change to another command.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=.5)
top = Tk()
movie1 = ("/home/pi/Videos/VID_chap1.mp4")
movie2 = ("/home/pi/Videos/VID_chap2.mp4")
movie3 = ("/home/pi/Videos/VID_chap3.mp4")

def vid1():
   os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
   omxc = Popen(['omxplayer','--layer','2','--win','0,0,800,481', movie1])
   pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"01-Subprogram-serial.py"])
#   subprocess.popen.kill(pid) <This not works

def vid2():
   os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
   omxc = Popen(['omxplayer','--layer','2','--win','0,0,800,481', movie2])
   pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"02-Subprogram-serial.py"])
#   subprocess.popen.kill(pid) <This not works

def vid3():
   os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
   omxc = Popen(['omxplayer','--layer','2','--win','0,0,800,481', movie3])
   pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"03-Subprogram-serial.py"])
#   subprocess.popen.kill(pid) <This not works


B = Button(top, text ="Asean 1", command = vid1)
C = Button(top, text ="Asean 2", command = vid2)
D = Button(top, text ="Asean 3", command = vid3)


B.pack()
C.pack()
D.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

I would like to kill the previous subprocess before it starts a new one

Comment: `Popen()` does not return a PID. It returns a `Popen` object on which you can run `.terminate()` or `.kill()`. Also you might want to use list, loops and parameterized function to reduce code repetitions.